# VBA looping through values in two excel columns

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to loop through two excel columns and determine if the values in the first column are present in the second column. I am fairly new to programming in VBA and haven't programmed in a while.

My code, when I run it via F8, if it finds a value it will write "Match" but it will keep looping and eventually rewrite it to "No Match". Can you please tell me how to fix this.

Thank you

[image]

```
Sub loopDb()

    Set dbsheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set dbsheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    lr1 = dbsheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lr2 = dbsheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 2 To lr1
        act1 = dbsheet1.Cells(x, 1)

        For y = 2 To lr2
            act2 = dbsheet2.Cells(y, 1)

            If act2 = act1 Then
                dbsheet2.Cells(y, 3).Value = "Match"

            Else
                dbsheet2.Cells(y, 3).Value = "No match"
            End If
        Next y

    Next x


End Sub
```

Comment: Is it intended, that you are comparing column A in two different sheets?

Comment: Why don't you just use this in column C?
 `IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2,$A$2:$A$16,0)),"Match","No match")`

Comment: Yes yes, I am comparing columns in two different sheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
Modify the If-Else as follows

```
If Not dbsheet2.Cells(y, 3).Value = "Match" Then 
'Only compare if previoulsy not done or resulted in "No match"
    If act2 = act1 Then
        dbsheet2.Cells(y, 3).Value = "Match"

    Else
        dbsheet2.Cells(y, 3).Value = "No match"
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `Exit For` after a Match

Like below:

```
If act2 = act1 Then
    dbsheet2.Cells(y, 3).Value = "Match"
    Exit For
Else
```

Answer (score 1):

Good that you came up with some code. There are much simpler ways of doing this, you could just use if you like,

**Approach 1:**

If data are in Columns `A and B`, enter the below formula in `Column C` and drag down,

```
=IF(IFERROR(MATCH(A1,B:B,0),FALSE),"Match","No Match")
```

[image]

This formula matches the value in column A to column B and prints based on true/false.

**Approach 2:**

Using the `Match` formula in VBA instead of running 2 different loops which might consume more time if there are more number of rows.

Below code also gives you a similar output.

```
Sub match()
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If IsError(Application.match(Cells(i, 1), Range("B:B"), 0)) Then
        Cells(i, 3) = "No Match"
    Else
        Cells(i, 3) = "Match"
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: your code is only comparing the values on the same row, not if the value in the left column is present anywhere in the right column.... Thanks anyway, this will be useful as well :)

Comment: @Mr.Riply The match formula will compare the value in one cell to all values in another column. May be you can give a try testing it